# SSH or VNC to my rpi not working after connecting to nordvpn

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I recently got a raspberry pi and installed raspbian OS. I am trying to use this box as a headless torrent box.

I am able to download torrents (with Deluge) but as soon as I connect to Nordvpn I loose the ability to connect remotely to the box via Putty(SSH) and VNC. I cant even ping the machine.

But I disconnect the Nordvpn app using a keyboard mouse and monitor then I can connect again from upstairs.

I kind of figured that the VPN is playing a game with me but I have no clue on how to proceed to fix this.

All my computers are on the same network using Ethernet (no wifi here)

Comment: After you connect to the VPN, your Pi will have a new internet-facing IP. Are you now attempting to ssh/VNC to this new IP? Your connection must now be routed through the external network, so you will also have to forward ports on your home router, and probably on your VPN too.

Comment: I actually figured it out, thanks to your last part. What i needed was to open the port on nordvpn using the command: nordvpn whitelist add port 22 
This gave me access to SSH... same command with port 5900 did it also for vncviewer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Welcome to U/L!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specifically about Unix or Linux.

Comment: VPN setups are known to change routes and/or create firewall rules. This is "expected" behavior.

Comment: Opening VNC port 5900 for the world is a really really bad idea

Answer (score 3):

Copying my answer from [How to remote access a raspberry pi connected to a VPN?](https://superuser.com/a/1526153/911977)

I had the same issue. I was using [NordVPN's Linux installation](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-and-Linux-Mint.htm) on a headless Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Buster. It would connect fine and any SSH connection that was up would persist however the Pi would not respond to pings or new SSH connections from the local network.

Running `nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/1` solved the issue. (Assuming your local network is `192.168.x.x`)

This is probably better and safer than whitelisting port 22.

Unlike its device apps, the cmd-line NordVPN blocks local networking by default.

If you also had this issue you can go to [Installing and using NordVPN on Debian, Ubuntu, and Linux Mint](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-and-Linux-Mint.htm), scroll down to the email link and let the NordVPN team know.

Comment: 192.168.0.0/16 is the subnet if you are going to limit it to your local network